# combing DELETE and LIKE in a sqlite statement

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to combine the two into a single statment, I would even settle for two seperate statements..... I know it must be possible, but how?

this is what I have tried:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myValue LIKE 'findme%';
```

and:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myValue LIKE 'findme%');
```

I get an error for the second statement saying something like, you can only have a single result for a LIKE statement with another statement...

Comment: The first query should work fine. What happens when you run it? Which SQLite version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first statement should work. Try without the final semicolon maybe?

The second one is not logical. Your subquery is not correlated to the first one and you cannot scan a table which is being modified. Actually what I would expect from this query, if it would ever run, is that all rows are deleted if there is a single row where your column matches…

If you wonder why the solutions with the `IN` clause work and not the `EXISTS`, it is because the `EXISTS` condition is evaluated for each row, whereas the `IN` set is evaluated once.

Comment: @gypsyDev: I suppose you are using an API? Next time you should probably state it in the question!

Comment: I think the version of sqlite is sqlite3? I am modifying the database from objective-C in an xCode project.

Comment: @gypsyDev: The statements should include the semicolon when you use the SQLite shell, but usually when you are writing your own program and use an interface to SQLite, you needn't them.

Answer (score 6):

If this statement returns any rows

```
select * from mytable where myvalue like 'findme%';
```

then replacing "select *" with "delete" should delete them.

```
delete from mytable where myvalue like 'findme%';
```

That should work with any SQL database, as long as you have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myValue IN (SELECT myValue FROM myTable WHERE myValue LIKE 'findme%');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to me:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE myValue LIKE 'findme%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` LIKE 'value%'
```